# Random number generator validation

Tags: java

I have created a random number generator which selects a random number dependant on the size of an array.

I was just hoping for someone to validate if what I have done is correct.

```
ArrayList<String> textArray = new ArrayList<String>();

textArray.add("hi");
textArray.add("yo");
textArray.add("no");
textArray.add("kool");

int randomNo = 0;
int Min = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < textArray.size(); i++) {
    randomNo = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((textArray.size() - Min) ));
}

System.out.println(randomNo);
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to select this random number? Just any integer between 0 and the size of the array?

Comment: I suggest you look at java.util.Random

Comment: [basic] tag doesn't stand for basic question. Please read the tag discription.

Comment: You have merely duplicated the behavior of `java.util.Random#nextInt(int max)`

Comment: Is this Java or Basic? You put both tags, and as far as I know they're different... (read the tag desciption, 'BASIC (Beginner’s All-purpose Symbolic Instruction Code) is a family of high-level programming languages designed to be easy to use.')

Comment: Why do you have a "for" loop? What does it add? You are only using the result of the last iteration...

Comment: Downvoting because the question is misleading. It has nothing to do with random number generator validation - it is a "read this to see if it makes sense" question, quite non-specific.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't validate your code, and I don't know what you're *actually* trying to do, but this seems more straightforward.

```
Random random = new Random();
randomNo = min + random.nextInt(textArray.size());
```

`randomNo` will have a value between `min` and `min + textArray.size()-1`, inclusive.

Read more about [`java.util.Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) .

Comment: This cuts out their `min` variable.

Comment: @tucuxi The min variable is declared in the question.

Comment: @Telthien: and set to zero, and never changed, and added a few times unnecessarily. It is therefore not used. Why not include variable 'i' too?

Comment: @tucuxi I'm going to assume the OP wanted to do something with `min`, and was putting it there as a placeholder.

Comment: Am I right in saying the min value would be 0 because the min amount of elements an array can hold is 0?

Comment: I don't know Sandeep, but, if I may pry, what do you _really_ want to do? Pick a random element from the ArrayList? You just want to get a random int between 0 and textArray.size()-1?